# Write a program to print the following pattern using a nested loop

Tags: java

The pattern of 2n+1 should be stair case

```
1
1 4
1 4 9
1 4 9 16
1 4 9 16 25
```

I'm trying to imply the 2n+1 equation into the for loop. I'm messing around for an hour but still can't think a way to solve this problem. This is what I have tried so far.

```
public class hw5{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=1 ; i <= 5; i++){
            for(int j=1; j <= 25; j = j + 3){
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your `j <= 25` is obviously wrong. Think about what the relationship between `i` and `j` in your code should be to achieve this kind of output

Comment: What are you expecting `j+3` to do? Each number is squared, has nothing to do with adding 3

Comment: Also, you seem to be missing spaces between each number... One suggestion: create a separate method that prints a whole row up to X numbers. Then call that method N times.

Answer (score 1):

The series printed is just the square of integers starting at one.  So just save each of the previous squares in a string.

```
String s = "";
int max = 5;
for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    System.out.println(s+= (i*i)+" ");
}
```

prints

```
1 
1 4 
1 4 9 
1 4 9 16 
1 4 9 16 25
```

However, starting with 1, the sum of the consecutive odd numbers also form perfect squares.  And `2n+1` is the representative form of an odd number for any integral value of `n`.

So you can also do it like this.

- compute the `sums` of all the `computed odd numbers` in the loop
- after each `sum` is computed, append to a string and print

```
int sum = 0;
String s = "";
int max = 5;
for (int n = 0; n < max; n++) {
    sum += (2*n + 1);
    System.out.println(s += sum + " " );
}
```

prints

```
1 
1 4 
1 4 9 
1 4 9 16 
1 4 9 16 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<i+1; j++) {
        System.out.print(j*j+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: An answer with code and no explanation is hardly an answer at all. Why is your code the right answer? What was the problem in the original and how did you address it?